# How to erase duplicate element in vector, efficiently

Tags: c++

I have

```
 vector<string> data ; // I hold some usernames in it
```

In that vector, I have duplicate element(s), so I want erase this/these element(s).Are there any algorithm or library function to erase duplicate element(s)?

```
ex :
    In data;
           abba, abraham, edie, Abba, edie
    After operation;
           abba, abraham, edie, Abba
```

Comment: Is the relative order of the elements important ? ie, do you care about the elements being shuffled around during the operations or do you want to obtain a sequence in the exact same order ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can sort the elements in the container, the straightforward and relatively efficient solution would be:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
data.erase(std::unique(data.begin(), data.end()), data.end());
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `stable_sort` here?

Comment: @Naveen:  Why?  You only need a stable sort if the relative position of equivalent elements matters, and that obviously doesn't matter if you're just going to remove duplicates anyway.

Comment: unless you specifically want to keep the first occurrence of the equivalence group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a really good way to do it.
What I would do is sort (in a different array, if you need the original in tact) and then run through it.

Answer (score 0):

"set" does not allow duplicates. You can use that to filter out duplicates.

1. Create a set
2. Add all usernames to set
3. Create a new vector
4. Add all elements from set to vector

Comment: But that will not preserve the order present in the `vector`.

Comment: Yes it wont. If you want to preserve order, complexity would increase. Basically create a new vector, for each item in existing vector {if it exists in set, do nothing, else add it to set and add it to target vecotr}

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it efficiently, then should do an in place sort first, and then go through the container by yourself instead of using std::unique, fetch unique items into a new vector, at then end do a swap.

I just checked the source code of std::unique, it will do a lot move when finding one duplicate, move hurts vector's performance.

Comment: `std::unique` should only require a single pass through the sorted sequence.  What do you mean by "it will do a lot [of] move[s] when finding one duplicate"?

Comment: it is a single pass through, but each time it finds a duplicate, it needs to move that to the end. 0 1 1 2 2 3 -> 0 1 2 2 3 1 -> 0 1 2 3 1 2.